# How are we protecting our heads this year? With Hats!

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

Once again, the time of the year has come when we have to decide whether we want to participate in the [Winter Bash](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/).

The event will start on 14 December 2015 and run up to and
including 03 January 2016. Users will be able to see all the hats they've
earned on http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com. That site will also have
an FAQ to explain how things work.

Individual users who don't want to participate, don't want to see hats,
and/or are generally anti-hat will have an "I hate hats" option available, like in previous years.
And just like last time, at the end of the event, all hats will go back
into storage.

If we don't want to participate in this year's Winter Bash, we need to give note of that until the tenth, so make up your minds:

#### Do we want hats?

---

The majority of voters said Aye, so there will be hats, there will be madness, and there will probably also be an Alice somewhere.

Comment: How are we protecting our heads? Well, that depends on _what_ we are protecting our heads from. Is there a snowball coming at our heads? an ACME anvil? What do you know about an imminent threat to our heads? Why are you being so secretive?

Comment: Just a side comment: out of 222576 users (according to SEDE), 74725 were created in 2015, which is 33.6%. Something to consider for old-timers who may well be tired of hats themselves: these users didn't have a chance to participate in WinterBash yet.

Comment: if people have the option not to see hats, why are we taking a poll in the first place? Those who are against can just click on the option :D

Comment: As a new user in 2015 can there please be more information about what is WinterBash. The link took me to a bunch of stick figures running around making (I think) numbers (I think its a countdown clock). It doesn't explain the event or even what a hat is.

Comment: @IanMiller Basically during the Winter Bash event there will be some tasks (_e.g._, voting on a certain kind of post, or posting on a particular day, or annoying a particular SE employee) which, when completed, will award you with a "hat" to be "worn" by your avatar. Here are a couple blog posts about last year's Winter Bash that _might_ give you a better idea: [Winter Bash 2014](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/12/winter-bash-2014/), [So long Winter Bash 2014](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/01/so-long-winter-bash-2014/).

Comment: Side note: Winter Bash is currently running in test mode behind the scenes, and except for Stack Overflow (which wins through sheer volume), math.se is leading the pack by a long shot with 9,002 hats earned in five days, compared to the runner-up site with 5,611 hats.

Comment: @balpha How many secret hats have been won so far? Is one of the secret hats "balpha boat" this year? Did I just get it?

Comment: Hats are good. They keep your head warm and protect against the sun.

Comment: @Ant Some effects of Winter Bash are still visible to those who opt out, due to the actions that users take to earn certain hats. (Example: rumor has it that one of hats will be for posting on meta on a particular day; these posts will not be invisible to those who opt out.)

Comment: 6 months too late for a winter bash, for those of us South of the Equator. Down with Borealocentrism!

Comment: @GerryMyerson Now is the _winter of your discontent_.

Comment: Can we change "I hate hats" to "sod off, I don't want imaginary clothing to go with my imaginary points" - my problem is not with hats.

Comment: @Alec I doubt you can convince the powers that be to use that sort of language (they're all older than 14 as far as I know). But you can of course make a userscript to rename the option on your side.

Comment: @DanielFischer you can change the language, the spirit of the message is what matters. As for controlling 14 year olds; I don't know enough to comment either way. I have no reason to doubt you know what controls the underaged though.

Comment: @Alec You can make a feature-request on [meta.se] to rename the button "Ugh, no, I don't want imaginary clothing to go with my imaginary points". Probably would be too late for this year, but maybe next. As for the remainder of your comment, I have no idea what you mean. I wouldn't propose impossible things like squaring a circle or controlling 14 year olds.

Comment: You can control pretty much all ages with fear @DanielFischer - kindness can be ineffective on the young. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Apparently two users are illiterate and downvoted the "Aye!" post...

Comment: Come on, if you need more reason to vote "Aye"... https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/Hilbert.jpg

Comment: @Najib What would you make of a user who upvotes both Aye and Nay? (I won't up/down either one).

Comment: @Norma: It's like seeing the wind. You don't actually see it, you see how the leaves move. Or sometimes how trees are taken down. Or how dust and sand particles are carried across the great plains...

Answer (score 114, accepted):

## Aye!

This awesome dude

[image]

knew how to wear hats, **and so do we!**

<sub>Image of Fejér Lipót from wikipedia, by user [MessinaRagazza](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:MessinaRagazza)</sub>

Answer (score 32):

## Nay!

Like this great man

[image]

we prove our theorems with our **bare heads!**

Comment: We will never win.

Comment: @GitGud A hat makes you taller ;)

Comment: @Git Gud: We can also look at that positively, and claim that we are winning in the race to who's losing this poll! :(