# Did I miss this year's hat discussion?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

It seems to me that every year we get asked here on meta whether we want hats on main. See ['Tis the season to be...](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25370/tis-the-season-to-be) and [How are we protecting our heads this year? With Hats!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22113/how-are-we-protecting-our-heads-this-year-with-hats) and [Would you like some hats? Yes, please!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17368/would-you-like-some-hats-yes-please). So I was surprised to get a hat earlier today, without having seen the annual discussion of whether we wanted them, how to opt out, etc.

Did I miss it? or was it just decided somewhere that since we've had them three years running, we must all want them?

Comment: No. There wasn't any. Unfortunately. I guess that after so many years of the discussion going almost entirely towards "let's have hats", they decided to stop taking them. But I liked to have my voice heard about how much I despise this thing...

Comment: re "we must all want them?" As usual you can turn them off if you prefer.

Comment: Well, I've got one, today, and as long as it's my decision to wear it or not (of course, I won't) that's fine with me.

Comment: Why do people hate the hats so much?  I can't understand having a strong feeling one way or another for something that seems so inconsequential.

Comment: N/m, I [found one reason](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25370/tis-the-season-to-be#comment99943_25370).  Didn't realize that was such an issue.

Comment: The less mathematics the more stupidity. The more stupidity the less mathematics.

Comment: Off-topic but if you allow the idle curiosity: do you mind that for all I know the community on MO was **never** asked what they want? The moderators simply decided.  cc @Asaf

Comment: @quid: No, but I feel there is some difference there on this topic.

Comment: Which would be what exactly? @Asaf (Incidentally some  high-profile users on MO expressed that they would want them. Still there never was poll to the best of my knowledge.)

Comment: @quid, no, I don't mind. I have no strong opinions at present on whether any particular site should be asked what they want, I'm just sensitive to change, and when something has gone one way for several years and then it goes a different way I'm curious as to what the story is.

Comment: @quid: I sort of feel that MathOverflow had this more professional "curmudgeon-y" side. I don't mind it being brought up for discussion, but it would feel odd. Just like I know how the discussion would end here, of course, but MSE is less strict and less "not festive". Not to mention, of course, that Hat Chasers are a thing, and keeping them away from MO is definitely on higher priority than having hats.

Comment: @quid: And just to make this complete, $$\huge\widehat{\mathfrak{quid}}.$$

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In preceding years per-site moderators were asked what their site wants. On this site, the moderators then launched a poll to base the decision on that result.

This year per-site moderators on sites that have a history of approving participation were not asked to begin with, and thus there was no trigger-event (or clear motivation) for a poll.

If it is found relevant (which it seems it is) we could still do such polls or have discussions to see how opinions evolve. For example, this time we could do it after the event finished to see how it was liked in actual practice.